# ARIMA model Prediction Vs Actual differences

Tags: python-3.x, statsmodels

I have daily sales data for the year 2018 and have run through ARIMA modeling by applying grid search(for loops), got optimal values like (0,1,2) and RMSE value 61.562.

My Naive Forecast model RMSE value(126.39) is lesser than ARIMA RMSE(61.562), so I believe the ARIMA model is doing good?

Am having trouble in understanding the differences between predicted vs expected values of ARIMA and wanted to know whether a model performer well or not and differences are acceptable.

Have attached screenshot of ARIMA test & prediction plot.

[image: Predict Vs Test]

Output of ARIMA

```
Train Set Lenght: 736
Test Set Lenght: 380
>Predicted=15.584, Expected= 20
>Predicted=18.602, Expected= 10
>Predicted=14.051, Expected= 30
>Predicted=22.576, Expected= 60
>Predicted=34.849, Expected= 10
>Predicted=16.423, Expected= 50
>Predicted=35.823, Expected= 54
>Predicted=36.277, Expected=  6
>Predicted=19.700, Expected= 35
>Predicted=32.607, Expected=  1
>Predicted=16.107, Expected= 36
>Predicted=31.214, Expected= 20
>Predicted=22.272, Expected=  4
>Predicted=17.035, Expected=  4
>Predicted=15.497, Expected=  8
>Predicted=15.150, Expected=  3
>Predicted=11.664, Expected=  3
>Predicted=10.629, Expected=  3
>Predicted=9.278, Expected=  3
>Predicted=8.268, Expected=  4
>Predicted=7.810, Expected=  4
>Predicted=7.114, Expected=  4
>Predicted=6.610, Expected=  4
>Predicted=6.168, Expected=  2
>Predicted=4.964, Expected= 12
>Predicted=8.790, Expected= 16
```

```
ARIMA Code snippet
train_series=north_top_painter_df["Volume"].values
train_size = int(len(train_series) * 0.66)
x_train, x_test = train_series[0:train_size], train_series[train_size:]
print('Train Set Lenght:',len(x_train))
print('Test Set Lenght:',len(x_test))
# walk-forward validation
history = [i for i in x_train]
predictions = list()

for i in range(len(x_test)):
  # predict
  model = ARIMA(history, order=(0,1,2))
  model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)
  #y_pred=model_fit.predict(start=len(train), end=len(train)+len(test)-1, dynamic=False)
  y_pred = model_fit.forecast()[0]
  predictions.append(y_pred)
  #observation
  test_obs = x_test[i]
  history.append(test_obs)
  print('>Predicted=%.3f, Expected=%3.f' % (y_pred, test_obs))
# report performance
rmse = sqrt(mean_squared_error(x_test, predictions))
print('RMSE: %.3f' % rmse)
plt.plot(x_test, label = "Test",color='blue') 
#plt.plot(y_pred)
plt.plot(predictions, color = 'red', label = "Predict") 
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can someone answer please.